# give permissions to specific files inside a folder with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plesk

I have installed a wordpress site to my dedicated server. I made a script that will rename the footer.php to another filename and if i run it from my browser it works correctly.

So i want to do it via scheduled task from plesk panel 11 but i cannot achieve it.
I tried to run it through ssh but i got the following errors:

Resolving www. mywebpage.com.. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to www.mywebpage.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2013-11-25 18:53:11 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

So i believe that .htaccess is blocking this. Can anyone tell me how to give access to specific folder and specific files inside .htaccess?

i tried this to plesk schedule: wget http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/worldwide/rename.php

And the rename.php is:

```
<?php
rename("footer.php","footersecond.php");
rename("footernew.php","footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: What is in your .htaccess and what kind of permalinks do you use? Default wp .htacces does not block php files, it just redirects all urls that are neither existing files nor directories to index.php
Plesk on the other hand may block it. It has many restrictions that are almost impossible to get rid off. You can work around this by modifying your script a bit, so you don't need to execute it using cron.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to run execute php script from shell? Create cron task with command line like

```
php http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/worldwide/rename.php
```